# How can I open react-devtools?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, react-devtools

I am trying to install and run react-devtools. I am following this guide to do that: https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/blob/master/packages/react-devtools/README.md

The install seems to go ok:

[image]

To verify it installed correctly I do this command:

[image]

And I go to that directory and verify there is a folder called react-devtools.

To open the tools the docs indicate I should do this:

[image]

Back in my project directory I run this command:

[image]

And it says command not found. So it looks like I have installed the devtools, but I am unable to open them. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which browser you are using ? You can install it as an extension

Comment: I just need to have this installed and running to fix a bug in the RN development environment.

Comment: Download this, its super easy to setup - https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger

Answer (score 13):

Maybe this is what you want

Fix not run react-devtools

Option 1:

```
npm uninstall -g react-devtools
npm uninstall -g electron
npm install -g --verbose react-devtools
```

Option 2: (Fix in Linux, MacOSX)

```
sudo npm install -g react-devtools --unsafe-perm=true
```

Refer: [react-devtools-command-not-found](http://www.jundat95.com/2018/05/react-devtools-command-not-found.html)

Answer (score 4):

if you want to run project level only do the following steps

1. Install using `yarn add --dev react-devtools`
2. Run `yarn run react-devtools`

Answer (score 2):

To run react-devtools you can run either of the following commands depending on your package manager.

If using yarn:
`yarn run react-devtools`

If using npm:
`npm run react-devtools`

Answer (score 0):

The real problem here is you are not giving "super user" permissions for the node package manager for installing the "react-devtools" globally.

Try this command it will fix your problem

```
sudo npm install -g react-devtools
```

When ignore the `-g` parameter in the command npm will install the react-devtools in directory that you currently working in. In your case the home directory.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into same problem.
So here how it actually worked for me.

```
 npm uninstall react-devtools
 npx react-devtools
```